in quarkus 3.14.2 derbydb is not working anymore
When creating a simple quarkus app in version 3.14.2 with panache, derbydb and one entity now an error message occurs. The class ProductVersionHolder of derby-drivers is not found.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/shared/common/info/ProductVersionHolder
This happens when using an local db-instance and also when using the dev-service for derby.
When using Quarkus 3.8.6 all works fine.
Can anybody help?
Thank you.
Thomas
